# how to add data into to database with foreach in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to move all the data from the `post` table into the `CityPost` table, I use `foreach` but why only one data entry,

```
 $store = new CityPost;
           $post = Post::all();
           foreach($post as $p){
               $store->user_id = 14; 
               $store->title = $v->title;
               $store->desc = $v->desc;
               $store->save();
           }
           dd($store);
```

I want all `user_id` in the `PostCity` table to be 14

Comment: because you only created one new model instance after the first save it now has an id and every call to save after that is just an update on the same record

Answer (score 5):

You should create CityPost model in foreach:

```
       $post = Post::all();
       foreach($post as $p){
           $store = new CityPost;
           $store->user_id = 14; 
           $store->title = $v->title;
           $store->desc = $v->desc;
           $store->save();        
       }
       dd($store);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do is try different way like below

```
$post = Post::all();
$stores = [];
foreach($post as $p){
    $store = new CityPost;
    $store->user_id = 14; 
    $store->title = $v->title;
    $store->desc = $v->desc;
    $stores[] = $store->save();

   //if $store->save() is boolean then you can use create method use save() or create() only one

   $new = CityPost::create(['user_id'=>14,'title'=>$p->title,'desc'=>$p->desc]);
   $stores[] = $new;
}
dd($stores);
```

or you can try another way like bulk update without calling **DB** multiple time

```
    $post = Post::all();
    $data = [];
    foreach($post as $p){
        $store->user_id = 14; 
        $store->title = $v->title;
        $store->desc = $v->desc;
        $data[] = ['user_id'=>$store->user_id,'title'=>$p->title,'desc'=>$p->desc];
    }
    CityPost::insert($data);
```

Comment: `save` returns a bool and in your first example you are updating `$store` not creating new instances, which is the same problem the OP has in their code currently

Comment: btw there isn't a question of whether `save` returns bool or not, it does return bool ... thanks for clarifying your answer :)

Comment: i have put both so developer can select prefer one . i hope he won't use both :)